# OpenGL rendering causes graphical glitch

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, sfml, immediate-mode

Code is below.  When the program runs, it generates a more or less correct image, but there are some graphical glitches.  Here are some images:[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3].  Any ideas on what could be causing this?    The weirdest part is that the issue appears to form on triangles, even though the image is being drawn with polygons (quads).

```
void buildList() {
    cubelist = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(cubelist,GL_COMPILE);

    // Multi-colored side - FRONT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3b(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5);
    // Black side - BACK
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3b(0,0,0);
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, 0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Purple side - RIGHT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(  1.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Green side - LEFT
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(   0.0,  1.0,  0.0 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Blue side - TOP
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(   0.0,  0.0,  1.0 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5,  0.5,  0.5 );
    glEnd();

    // Red side - BOTTOM
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(   1.0,  0.0,  0.0 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex3f(  0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5,  0.5 );
    glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
    glEnd();
    glEndList();
}

void setupGL() {
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);
}

int main(int, char const**)
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(1600, 1200), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Default, sf::ContextSettings(32));
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    //initWorld();
    setupGL();
    buildList();

    while (running)
    {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        handleInput(window);
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // Close window: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                running = false;
            }

            // Escape pressed: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        glCallList(cubelist);

        // Update the window (c is a "Camera" object that just sets the perspective.   I can provide code if necessary)
        c.draw();
        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT:  So changing the GL_POLYGONS statements to GL_QUADS seemed to fix the problem, but I'm still somewhat curious as to why.

Comment: Why doesn't your `Multi-colored side - FRONT`'s `glBegin()` have a corresponding `glEnd()`?  It's not optional.

Comment: @genpfault they do, all except the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first `glBegin` doesn't have a matching `glEnd`, this causes all the other `glBegin`s to be ignored until the next `glEnd`. This means the front face leaked out to the back face.

That said immediate mode and the related displayList are deprecated, instead look into VBOs to store the vertex data.